# getnameinfo, C, IPv6 always gives 0.0.0.0

Tags: c, gethostbyname

I tried to implement a simple DNSIPv6 server in C. This is a very simple and first approach to do this. I read here: https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/gethostbynameman.html that instead of using `gethostbyname` I should use `getnameinfo`. It works well with IPv6, but fails with IPv6 - when I provide IPv6, it gives me 0.0.0.0 instead of the hostname:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 1024

int main()
{
    char host[SIZE];
    char service[SIZE];

    struct sockaddr_in6 sa;
    sa.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    inet_pton(AF_INET6, "64:ff9b::d8da:e477", &sa.sin6_addr);

    int res = getnameinfo((struct sockaddr*)&sa, sizeof(sa), host, sizeof(host), service, sizeof(service), 0);

    if(res)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Hostname: %s\n", host);
        printf("Service: %s\n", service);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: With the given IP in my local /etc/hosts file, this program returns the expected hostname.  Are you able to resolve this hostname with a command line utility like `nslookup` or `ping6`?

Comment: @dbush: I tried to use `ping6` : `ping6  2607:f8b0:4003:c00::6a
connect: Network is unreachable`. Is it possible to have both IPv4 and IPv6, just to test this?

Comment: Use the name you expect the program to return, not the IP.  That will tell you if name resolution is working.  Also, be sure to check the return value of `inet_pton`.